# group rows based on ID and then return the row with the lowest date per ID grouping

Tags: sql

suppose you have a data set having 3 columns: ID, user, date.

is it possible to filter the data based on the minimum date even if some of the rows have identical IDs?

sorry if the question is a bit unclear. hopefully the image below  will help clear things.

there are two records having ID=1, with different users as well as dates. what i want to retrieve is the record having an ID=1, USER=A, DATE=2013-01-20 because its date is earlier than that of the second record (ID=1, USER=A, DATE=2013-01-21)

i want to achieve the same effect for the three records having an ID=2. the desired record is ID=2,USER=C,DATE=2013-10-20

basically i want to group these records by their IDs and then from that grouping, get the one with the lowest date

[image: data set + intended output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT id, user, date
FROM OriginalData od
WHERE date = (SELECT MIN(date) 
              FROM OriginalDate od1 
              WHERE od.id = od1.id)
```

Comment: Perfectly working as OP asked :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from table_name where date in 
( select MIN(date) from table_name)
```

Comment: Your sub-query returns a single value.

Comment: This is not what he asked for.

Comment: Agree with @PM77-1 that above query returns only Single Row

Answer (score 0):

You have tyo use `Group By` clause on `Id` attribute.

Use the following syntax

```
select * from tab1 where (id, date) in (select id, min(date) from tab1 group by(id))
```

Comment: Will work in MySql only.

Comment: Have you tested in other platforms?

Comment: I do not have to. You will get an error that you have fields (namely, user and date that are neither in `GROUP BY` nor aggregated. Only MySql implements `GROUP BY` extensions.  Try SQL Server or Oracle, among others.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12863928/sql-group-by-error-not-a-group-by-expression